# What type of 3D printer is this?

Tags: resin, part-identification

I have found a video about Invisalign. I saw a 3D printer in the video but I did not understand its type. Can you help me? Do you share a brief piece of information about its type?

Below is the video on YouTube.

Comment: this is an industrial machine, not a "desktop" machine, but it's a good question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the video, there is this still from [0:32](https://youtu.be/bKsGNrEKx9M?t=32):

[image]

The labeling is iPro 8000, which is a [3dSystems resin printer using SLA technology.](http://infocenter.3dsystems.com/product-library/sla/ipro-8000-9000)

Comment: Good eye, Trish!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the video at 37 seconds, it appears to be SLA or DLP.

Further reading: https://www.solidprint3d.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/SLA_vs_DLP.pdf